# How to create/generate a dataTable in Cucumber 7.3.4 (Gherkin) (dataTatble.create()) when I have two strings parameters

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

The question is rather generic. I will explain here more.
So I have this kind of step in cucumber:
And expect result to be "status_code" and response "200"
The parameters are strings that are later used to create a two rows dataTable which is created programmatically.

```
            NOT in this way: |status_code|                                                                     
                             |   200     |
```

The table was created this way:

```
public DataTable createDataTable(String columnName, String rowName) {
        List<List<String>> dataTableList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(columnName);
        List<String> rows = Arrays.asList(rowName);
        dataTableList.add(columns);
        dataTableList.add(rows);
        return DataTable.create(dataTableList);
    }
```

Before update to 7.3.4 this approach worked like a charm. But now I receive multiple errors
,when I am trying to use the tables created this way.

The error says:datatable was created without a converter.

When I am debugging code I can see that the TableConverter is empty indeed.And that is exactly the problem: I do not understand how to populate the converter part of a programmatically created  DataTabble.
Any thoughs?

Comment: How are you using the tables? There should be a set of methods that do some conversion without the need for a table converter. Check the source

Answer (score 4):

I will answer my question myself.The solution was rather simple.I just dug into the code and found the explanation.
The DataTable itself needs two parts:

- a registry to be converted and created
- tableConverter class

So adding those lines to the code and updating previous function solves the problem.These are the lines :

```
private static final DataTableTypeRegistry registry = new DataTableTypeRegistry(Locale.ENGLISH);
private static final DataTable.TableConverter tableConverter = new DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverter(registry);

public DataTable createDataTable(String columnName, String rowName) {
        List<List<String>> dataTableList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(columnName);
        List<String> rows = Arrays.asList(rowName);
        dataTableList.add(columns);
        dataTableList.add(rows);
        return DataTable.create(dataTableList,tableConverter);
    }
```

Basically, two lines of code and update in a function are solving the problem.
It was just not clear which converter the DataTable asks for.